# mysql how to use results of one query in a few unions

Tags: mysql

**EDIT:** mysql version: 5.7.34

I am querying my data to get counts on different group, I'm doing it in one query using union (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68879038/mysql-various-group-by-in-one-query) question)
here is my query

```
SELECT 'department' as group_name, department, NULL AS d_type, NULL AS country, NULL AS city, COUNT(trx.id)
FROM (<some query>) trx
GROUP BY department

UNION ALL

SELECT 'd_type', NULL, d_type, NULL, NULL, COUNT(trx.id)
FROM (<some query>) trx
GROUP BY d_type

UNION ALL

SELECT 'location', NULL, NULL, NULL, country, city, COUNT(trx.id)
FROM (<some query>)
GROUP BY country, city
```

this is my 'some query':

```
SELECT IFNULL(parent_id, child_id) as id,  department, d_type, country, city
FROM my_table
WHERE <some conditions..>
GROUP BY id
```

is there a way I can use the 'some query' in all unions with out writing it each time, **and with running it only once**? (currently it runs for each union)

Comment: Create a VIEW for your query: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL 8.x, you can use a [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions).

```
WITH trx AS (
    SELECT IFNULL(parent_id, child_id) as id,  department, d_type, country, city
    FROM my_table
    WHERE <some conditions..>
    GROUP BY id
)
SELECT ...
FROM trx
GROUP BY department

UNION ALL

SELECT ...
FROM trx
GROUP BY d_type

UNION ALL

SELECT ...
FROM trx
GROUP BY country, city
```

If not, define it as a view.

Comment: mysql version: 5.7.34, when using a view, it will run the 'some query' only once?
my problem is not to write the query each time- but rather improving performance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302615/mysql-views-performance